# django heroku requirements.txt errors on push

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, requirements.txt

I am deploying my django project/PWA using heroku.
I generated requirements.txt with

```
pip freeze > requirement.txt
```

Then, I deleted all the @... paths from requirement.txt because of the following error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.9
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.9
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Processing /C:/ci/argon2-cffi_1596828585465/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/ci/argon2-cffi_1596828585465/work'
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 15051a62cb1a7471031f124c1aa85ab62a1073c4
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 15051a62cb1a7471031f124c1aa85ab62a1073c4
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to nameless-sea-67566.
remote:
```

but, even after removing the @, it is still reading from the same non existent path.

This is the full contents of requirements.txt I have:

```
astroid
brotlipy==0.7.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi
charset-normalizer
colorama
cryptography
Django==2.1.5
django-crispy-forms==1.13.0
django-pwa==1.0.10
idna
isort
lazy-object-proxy
mccabe==0.6.1
olefile==0.46
Pillow
pycparser
pylint
pyOpenSSL
PySocks
pytz==2021.3
requests
six
toml
typed-ast
typing-extensions
urllib3==1.26.7
win-inet-pton
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.12.1
```

Comment: A "snippet" isn't sufficient, and that's a _lot_ of dependencies starting with `a`. I suspect you've got a ton of dependencies you don't actually need. This is one of many reasons virtual environments are valuable. Please [edit] your question and provide the _full_ error message.

Comment: I was using the wrong requirement.txt earlier(generated without activating virtual environment), I just edited and posted contents of the requirements.txt I have generated from inside the virtual environement. And the full logs of the error are also added.

Comment: I do not understand why after taking out the @ , it still has to look up 'cffi' in my local directory and not use pip install instead.

Comment: (a) Are you sure you committed this change and pushed that commit? (b) Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?